# Whats wrong with my insertion sort?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with my insertion sort. It seems as though for every increment of i, array[i] is copied to array[i+1] and so on until the whole array is filled with the original object array[i]`

```
public static void insertionSort(Course[] courseArray, String sortBy) {
    Course value;   // the next value from the unsorted list to be inserted into the sorted list
    int i;     // i is a pointer to an item in the unsorted list
    int j;    // j is a pointer to an item in the sorted list; originally the sorted list is just a[0]

    for (i = 1; i < courseArray.length - 1; i++) 
    {

        value = courseArray[i];

        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && (courseArray[j].compareByCourse(value)) < 0) {
            courseArray[j + 1] = courseArray[j];

            j = j - 1;

        }
        courseArray[i + 1] = value;

        System.out.println("i= " + i + "--------------------------------------");

        for (int p = 0; p < courseArray.length; p++) 
        {
            System.out.println(courseArray[p].toString());
        }

    }//end for

}//end insertionSort()`
```

I have looked at many insertion sort examples and I feel as though I wrote this correctly but apparently, I am wrong.

Comment: How does it not work? What output are you expecting and what are you getting? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Array is 0 based. Change loop to start i from 0.

Comment: `courseArray[i + 1] = value;` should be `courseArray[j + 1] = value;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to SWAP (exchange) the values in the inner loop (with if condition).

You are just overwriting one of them.

Good luck.